# Kohana 3.1.1 Routing problem with jQuery tabs

Tags: jquery-ui, kohana

In order to ask my question, I need to explain my code first...

I have a controller (Controller_App) which extends Controller_Template. Inside the controller's template view, I have jQuery tabs with 3 tabs.  When I access the URI: `/view/26`, the following route kicks in:

```
Route::set('view_story', '<action>/<id>(/<stuff>)', array(
    'action'    => 'view',
    'id'        => '\d+',
    'stuff'     => '.*',
))
->defaults(array(
    'controller' => 'app',
));
```

The following function is then called in Controller_App and sets the URI of the "Explore" jQuery tab and makes it the default selection:

```
public function action_view($id)
    {
        $this->template->controller['explore'] = Route::get('explore')
            ->uri(array(
                'controller' => 'explore',
                'id'         => $id,
            ));
        $this->template->default_tab = 2;
    }
```

Here is my "explore" route:

```
Route::set('explore', '<controller>/<id>', array(
    'controller'    => 'explore',
    'id'            => '\d+',
))
->defaults(array(
    'action'    => 'index',
));
```

**The problem:**
When I try to access a story with the URL: "myhost.com/view/26", it sets everything okay, but it thinks that "/view" is a directory, so it tries to call "myhost.com/view/explore/26. Since there is no controller called "view", I get a 404 error.  I was able to get around the 404 error by creating the following route:

```
Route::set('explore', '(<directory>/)<controller>/<id>', array(
    'directory'     => 'view',
    'controller'    => 'explore',
    'id'            => '\d+',
))
->defaults(array(
    'directory' => '',
    'action'    => 'index',
));
```

...and then changing my function to:

```
public function action_view($id)
    {
        $this->template->controller['explore'] = Route::get('explore')
            ->uri(array(
                'directory'  => '',
                'controller' => 'explore',
                'action'     => 'index',
                'id'         => $id,
            ));
        $this->template->default_tab = 2;
    }
```

But when the page loads, it calls jQuery.get() but it's trying to call the PHP file under the "/view" directory instead of the current directory.

I don't know if this is a simple routing issue, or if I'm even barking up the right tree at all. But I've tried all different combinations of routes and can't for the life of me figure this out. All suggestions are appreciated!

Thanks,
Brian

Comment: You say when you navigate to `myhost.com/view/26` everything is OK, but it tries to call `myhost.com/view/explore/26`? What tries to call `myhost.com/view/explore/26`? Maybe you need to wrap `URL::site()` around the route output?

Comment: @davgothic - Sorry, it was pretty late for me last night when I posted this. ;) In the `action_view` function (the first one), it constructs a route for the explore controller. But when it does this, it keeps the `/view` directory and prepends that to my route. If I modify the route definition and alter my `action_view` function (as shown in the 2nd example), it fixes the problem but then my AJAX calls are messed up, because instead of calling `core/stories` it calls `/view/core/stories`. It's like I need to change my current working directly up one level...

Answer (score 0):

[`Route::uri(...)`](http://kohanaframework.org/3.1/guide/api/Route#uri) generates uris which aren't absolute.
Switch to using [`Route::url(...)`](http://kohanaframework.org/3.1/guide/api/Route#url) and you should be good to go.

`Route::url(...)` is a shortcut for passing `Route::uri(...)` through `URL::site(...)`.

```
public function action_view($id)
{
    $this->template->controller['explore'] = Route::get('explore')
        ->url(array(
            'controller' => 'explore',
            'id'         => $id,
        ));
    $this->template->default_tab = 2;
}
```

Comment: The problem is when making an AJAX call from within my external JS file.  Where would I put the Route/URL method?

Comment: my hunch was that the AJAX code has been given a relative URI, rather than an absolute one (i.e `foo.html` rather than `/foo.html`), as a result the code tries to find a dir from the current url and then add the relative url to it. Change it where you make this assignment: `$this->template->controller['explore'] = ..`